# typedef volatile struct is recognized as anonymous in clang ast

Tags: c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, volatile

I have the following C code:

```
typedef volatile struct
{
   unsigned short   field1;    
   unsigned int     field2;        
} new_struct_t_1;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned short   field1;    
   unsigned int     field2;        
} new_struct_t_2;
```

When running clang to generate AST dump for this code I get that the struct with the qualifier `volatile` is anonymous while the one without is not marked as anonymous.

I'm running the following command:

```
clang-8 -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only /tmp/2.c
```

and the result is:

```
|-RecordDecl 0x401c6e8 </tmp/2.c:1:18, line:5:1> line:1:18 struct definition
| |-FieldDecl 0x40794d0 <line:3:4, col:21> col:21 field1 'unsigned short'
| `-FieldDecl 0x4079530 <line:4:4, col:21> col:21 field2 'unsigned int'
|-TypedefDecl 0x40795d8 <line:1:1, line:5:3> col:3 new_struct_t_1 'volatile struct (anonymous struct at /tmp/2.c:1:18)':'volatile struct (anonymous at /tmp/2.c:1:18)'
| `-QualType 0x4079584 'volatile struct (anonymous struct at /tmp/2.c:1:18)' volatile
|   `-ElaboratedType 0x4079580 'struct (anonymous struct at /tmp/2.c:1:18)' sugar
|     `-RecordType 0x401c760 'struct (anonymous at /tmp/2.c:1:18)'
|       `-Record 0x401c6e8 ''
|-RecordDecl 0x4079640 <line:7:9, line:11:1> line:7:9 struct definition
| |-FieldDecl 0x40796f8 <line:9:4, col:21> col:21 field1 'unsigned short'
| `-FieldDecl 0x4079758 <line:10:4, col:21> col:21 field2 'unsigned int'
`-TypedefDecl 0x40797f8 <line:7:1, line:11:3> col:3 new_struct_t_2 'struct new_struct_t_2':'new_struct_t_2'
  `-ElaboratedType 0x40797a0 'struct new_struct_t_2' sugar
    `-RecordType 0x40796c0 'new_struct_t_2'
      `-Record 0x4079640 ''
```

Does anyone can explain why the addition of the qualifier `volatile` causes the AST to recognize this struct as anonymous?

Comment: Is that your *exact* code? Because both would, in normal circumstances, be anonymous structs (i.e. they don't have a name after `struct`).

Comment: This is an example taken from a real code. As I understand, and it is as you mentioned, I thought that both structs are anonymous, but as we can see in the AST dump from clang only the 'new_struct_t_1' which is also defined as volatile is marked as anonymous.

Comment: Does it happen if you remove `volatile`?

Comment: At a guess, the simple typedef doesn't need any entry, because it can use the typedef namer as a fully descriptive "sugar" entry, and this is common C parlance, while the volatile needs a root entry from which to hang the "volatile" qualifier. It would be strange to attach the volatile tag to the named typedef.

Comment: @JL2210, the reason I've put the 2 structures is to show that without volatile AST dump does not add the anonymous tag while having it, AST dump prints anonymous

Comment: @sagi I know, but it may have to do with the two structures being sequential.

Comment: @JL2210 I've split the structs into 2 different files and got the same result

Comment: I don't know, then. File a bug and see what the maintainers respond with.